# Blank screen recording with navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, screen-recording, get-display-media

We make a product that records the user's screen from the browser, using `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia` ; it works nicely everywhere but we face 1 issue for 1 client, and I was wondering if anyone had this issue before: with Chrome browser (99.0.4844.83) on MacOS (Monterey) the screen recording ends up with a dark blank screen video with no apparent reason.

We even sent him to [this online testing tool](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/) for webRTC recording, and the result is the same: a dark video.

There is no permission error, there is only one screen on the computer and one video stream, and the resulting video file has 1 video track with the proper screen size, and the correct duration. Plus, during the recording we can see the video stream correctly mirrored into a `video` element that shows the correct video stream.

But at the end, when the browser put the resulting blob in a video file, this one is just blank, like a stale dark rectangle, and we can't figure out why? Any clue?

Comment: there has been a very recent issue on macos:https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1307502
This might not be fully fixed.

Comment: you're definately right, we went though this too, but their recent release (yesterday at the time writing this) fixed the permission issue for all our users... And in this particular case the user had also that permission issue, but now it's fixed, only his video remains... blank.

Comment: the most recent change on that bug suggests it might not have fixed everything (but hopefully most of it)